# Getting syntax error saying Unexpected Token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I am returning a single element and I am putting the js code in `{}`, then why won't it work ?

```js
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';

const CardList=({robots})=>{
    
    return(
        <div>
            {const cardComponent = robots.map((user,i)=>
                {
                    return(
                        <Card id={robots[i].id} name={robots[i].name} email={robots[i].email} />
                        )
                }
                )
            }   
        </div>
        )
        
}
export default CardList;
```

Comment: could you show us the error message

Comment: You can only put expressions inside JSX curly braces. A variable declaration or assignment is a statement not an expression. If you don't know what "statement" and "expression" mean I suggest you research it because it's fundamental to much of programming.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define variables in the return statement of react stateless/functional component.

Try this :

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card";

const CardList = ({ robots }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {robots.map((user, i) => {
        return (
          <Card
            id={robots[i].id}
            name={robots[i].name}
            email={robots[i].email}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
export default CardList;
```

Answer (score 1):

The component is not formatted well. You are trying to assign inside the return statement in the JSX component which is why it is not working.

The below assignment is what is causing the issue.

```
const cardComponent = robots.map((user,i)=>
```

Please change it to below. Also it is recommended to provide `key` to each item that is rendered in a loop

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card";

const CardList = ({ robots }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {robots.map((user, i) => {
        return (
          <Card
            key={robots[i].id}
            id={robots[i].id}
            name={robots[i].name}
            email={robots[i].email}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
export default CardList;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `robots` is an array if `users` and each `user` is an object, then this should work.

```
const CardList = ({ robots }) => (
    <div>
        {robots.map((user, i) => (
            <Card 
                id={user.id} 
                name={user.name} 
                email={user.email}
                key={i}
            />
        ))}
    </div>
);
export default CardList;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, that you define variable cardComponent in the render.

you only need

`robots.map((user, i)=>...)`

Also you dont need to access the contents of each robots array entry by using `robots[i]`, as they are automatially assigned to the first argument of your map function (in this case `user`).

See the attached Codesandbox for a working version:

https://codesandbox.io/s/robots-z5b6h?file=/src/CardList.js